# Userform load with different initalisation

Tags: vba, userform

I currently have a UserForm that involves dates and times which loads when a button is pressed. When it appears it comes with example default values already filled in. However I have decided that I want the UserForm to also load when a cell is clicked on. However when the cell is clicked on I want the UserForm to appear with dates and times already filled in (based on the Cell location)

So far I have the following:
This is in the UserForm

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Set Duration Box default value to 1
DurationBox.Value = 1

'Set court one as default
OptionButton1.Value = True

'Set Default (example) Date
DateBox.Text = "Ex 22/05/2001"

'Set Default start time
StartBox.Text = "08:00"

'Set Default Number of weeks
WeeksBox.Text = 1
```

In the cells though I have the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim CurDate As String
Dim CurStart As String

If Target.Row > 6 And Target.Row < 21 And Target.Column > 5 And 
Target.Column < 13 Then
    CurRow = ActiveCell.Row
    CurCol = ActiveCell.Column
    CurDate = Cells(5, CurCol).Text
    CurStart = Cells(CurRow, 1).Text
    UserForm1.Show

End If

End Sub
```

When the UserForm loads in this in this way I want CurDate and CurStart to repalce the default DateBox and StartBox

However if I simply put:

```
'Set Default (example) Date
DateBox.Text = CurDate

'Set Default start time
StartBox.Text = CurStart
```

after loading the UserForm Firstly it doesnt do anything until after I have closed the UserForm and secondly it then throws up an error.

Essentialy I want to give the UserForm a different Initialization based on how it is activated. I could just have two UserForms that do exactly the same thing however the rest of the code is very long and its still liable to be changed.

Comment: Not an answer to your direct question. However, under `_SelectionChange` your `Target` is the active cell(s), so in your if statement you can refer to the `Target` instead of `ActiveCell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:
1. Move all (or most) of your code in `UserForm_Initialize` to `UserForm_Activate`. Then it will happen right after your `.Show` call.
2. Set the values from your calling code instead of in the form:

```
UserForm1.DateBox.Text = CurDate
UserForm1.Show
```

Comment: I couldn't get your first suggestion to work (It kept returning an error) but the second suggestion works fantastically

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use local variable of worksheet in a userform. You need declare them globally which you can do in a module.

Create a new module name something like "PublicDeclaration" and put public variables in there like:

```
Public NumOfWeeks as long
Public curStart as date
Public curDate as date
Public SelectionChange as boolean
```

In worksheet with selection change use global variable SelectionChange

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row > 6 And Target.Row < 21 And Target.Column > 5 And 
Target.Column < 13 Then
    SelectionChange = true
    CurRow = ActiveCell.Row
    CurCol = ActiveCell.Column
    CurDate = Cells(5, CurCol).Text
    CurStart = Cells(CurRow, 1).Text
    UserForm1.Show

End If

End Sub
```

and then use these variables in UserForm and in Worksheet_SelectionChange

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   if SelectionChange = false then
      'Set Duration Box default value to 1
      DurationBox.Value = 1

      'Set court one as default
      OptionButton1.Value = True

      'Set Default (example) Date
      DateBox.Text = "Ex 22/05/2001"

      'Set Default start time
      StartBox.Text = "08:00"

      'Set Default Number of weeks
      WeeksBox.Text = 1
   else
      DateBox.Text = curStart
      WeeksBox.Text = NumOfWeeks
```

and so on..

I am just not sure about NumOfWeeks curCol curRow and how you work with that but I hope you get the idea.